# Why do floating-point numbers have signed zeros?

Tags: java, floating-point, zero, negative-zero

Why do doubles have `-0` as well as `+0`?  What is the background and significance?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`-0` is (generally) treated as `0` *******. It can result when a *negative* floating-point number is so close to zero that it can be considered `0` (to be clear, I'm referring to [arithmetic underflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow), and the results of the following computations are interpreted as being *exactly* `±0`, not just really small numbers). e.g.

```
System.out.println(-1 / Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

```
-0.0
```

If we consider the same case with a *positive* number, we will receive our good old `0`:

```
System.out.println(1 / Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

```
0.0
```

---

******* Here's a case where using `-0.0` results in something different than when using `0.0`:

```
System.out.println(1 / 0.0);
System.out.println(1 / -0.0);
```

```
Infinity
-Infinity
```

This makes sense if we consider the function *`1 / x`*. As *`x`* approaches `0` from the *`+`*-side, we should get *positive* infinity, but as it approaches from the *`-`*-side, we should get *negative* infinity. The graph of the function should make this clear:

[image]

([source](http://www.sagemath.org/calctut/onesided.html))

In math-terms:

[image]

[image]

This illustrates one significant difference between `0` and `-0` in the computational sense.

---

Here are some relevant resources, some of which have been brought up already. I've included them for the sake of completeness:

- [Wikipedia article on signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)
- ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (See Signed Zero section)
- (PDF) ["Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit"](http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf) - an interesting paper by W. Kahan.

Answer (score 32):

From Wikipedia

> Signed zero is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic,
> `−0 = +0 = 0`.  In computing, existes the concept of **existence of
> two zeros** in some numbers representations, usually denoted by  `−0`
> and '+0', representing  **negative zero** and `+0` **positive zero**,
> respectively ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)).

> This occurs in the sign and magnitude and ones' complement [signed
> number representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) for integers, and in most floating point
> number representations. The number 0 is usually encoded as +0, but can
> be represented by either +0 or −0.
>
> According to the `IEEE 754 standard`, negative zero and positive zero
> should **compare as equal** with the usual (numerical) comparison
> operators, like the == operators of C and Java. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)).

When you have a **floating-point operation** that produces a result that is a **negative floating-point** number **close to zero**, but that can **not be represented** (by the computer) it produces a "-0.0". For example -`5.0 / Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY  ->  -0.0`.

This distinction between `-0.0` and `+0.0` gives the end-user more information than merely displaying a final result of `0`. Naturally, such a concept is really *only* useful in systems with a finite numerical representation limitation such as those of computers. In mathematics, one can represent any number, regardless of how close it is to zero.

`−0` and `+0` are the result of mathematical operations performed by computers that cause **[underflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow)**, similar to the `−00` or `+00` that result from operations that cause an **[overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow)**. For the operations that cause mathematical **indetermination**, the result is **NaN** (*e.g.,* 0/0).

**What's the difference between -0.0 and 0.0?**

In reality, both represent `0`. Furthermore, (-0.0 == 0.0) returns **true**. Nevertheless:

1. `1/-0.0` produces **-Infinity** while `1/0.0` produces **Infinity**.
2. `3 * (+0)` = **+0** and `+0/-3` = **-0**. The **sign rules** applies, when performing multiplications or division over a signed zero.

Mandatory reading "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#924)".

Answer (score 25):

See the section on "Signed Zero" in [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Zeros in Java float and double do not just represent true zero. They are also used as the result for any calculation whose exact result has too small a magnitude to be represented. There is a big difference, in many contexts, between underflow of a negative number and underflow of a positive number. For example, if `x` is a very small magnitude positive number, `1/x` should be positive infinity and `1/(-x)` should be negative infinity. Signed zero preserves the sign of underflow results.

Answer (score 10):

The canonical reference for the usefulness of signed zeros in floating-point is Kahan's paper "[Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions, or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit](http://port70.net/~nsz/articles/float/kahan_branch_cuts_complex_elementary_functions_1987.pdf)" (and some of his talks on the subject).

The short version is that in reasonably common engineering applications, the sign information that is preserved by having signed zero is necessary to get correct solutions from numerical methods.  The sign of zero has little meaning for most *real* operations, but when complex-valued functions are considered, or conformal mappings are used, the sign of zero may suddenly become quite critical.

It's also worth noting that the original (1985) `IEEE-754` committee considered, and rejected, supporting a *projective* mode for floating-point operations, under which there would only be a single unsigned infinity (+/-0 would be semantically identical in such a mode, so even if there were still two encodings, there would only be a single zero as well).