# Java signed zero and boxing

Tags: java, double, boxing

Lately I've written a project in Java and noticed a very strange feature with double/Double implementation. The double type in Java has two 0's, i.e. 0.0 and -0.0 (signed zero's). The strange thing is that:

```
0.0 == -0.0
```

evaluates to `true`, but:

```
new Double(0.0).equals(new Double(-0.0))
```

evaluates to `false`. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: The usual way to avoid this is to add `0.0`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8153449/823393) for a little more detail.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is all explained in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Note that in most cases, for two instances of class Double, d1 and d2, the value of d1.equals(d2) is true if and only if
>
> ```
>    d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()
> ```
>
> also has the value true. However, there are two exceptions:
>
> - If d1 and d2 both represent Double.NaN, then the equals method returns true, even though Double.NaN==Double.NaN has the value false.
> - **If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the equal test has the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value true.**
>
> This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.

---

Now you might ask why `0.0 == -0.0` is true. In fact they are not strictly identical. For example:

```
Double.doubleToRawLongBits(0.0) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(-0.0); //false
```

is false. However, the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) requires ("*in accordance with the rules of the IEEE 754 standard*") that:

> Positive zero and negative zero are considered equal.

hence `0.0 == -0.0` is true.

Comment: And the JLS requires that because the IEEE 754 requires it.

Comment: @ninjalj Indeed - Added that clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It important to undertand the use of signed zero in the Double class. (Loads of experienced Java programmers don't).

*The short answer is that (by definition) "-0.0 is less than 0.0" in all the methods provided by the Double class (that is, equals(), compare(), compareTo(), etc)*

Double allows all floating point numbers to be "totally ordered on a number line".
Primitives behave the way a user will think of things (a real world definition) ... 0d = -0d

The following snippets illustrate the behaviour ...

```
final double d1 = 0d, d2 = -0d;

System.out.println(d1 == d2); //prints ... true
System.out.println(d1 < d2);  //prints ... false
System.out.println(d2 < d1);  //prints ... false
System.out.println(Double.compare(d1, d2)); //prints ... 1
System.out.println(Double.compare(d2, d1)); //prints ... -1
```

There are other posts that are relevant and nicely explain the background ...

1: **[Why do floating-point numbers have signed zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544342/why-do-floating-points-have-signed-zeros)**

2: **[Why is Java's Double.compare(double, double) implemented the way it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726254/why-is-javas-double-comparedouble-double-implemented-the-way-it-is)**

And a word of caution ...

If you don't know that, in the Double class, **"-0.0 is less than 0.0"**, you may get caught out when using methods like **equals()** and **compare()** and **compareTo()** from Double in logic tests. For example, look at ...

```
final double d3 = -0d; // try this code with d3 = 0d; for comparison

if (d3 < 0d) {     
    System.out.println("Pay 1 million pounds penalty");
} else {           
    System.out.println("Good things happen"); // this line prints
}


if (Double.compare(d3, 0d) < 0) { //use Double.compare(d3, -0d) to match the above behaviour
    System.out.println("Pay 1 million pounds penalty"); // this line prints
} else {                              
    System.out.println("Good things happen"); 
}
```

and for equals you might try ... new Double(d3).equals(0d) || new Double(d3).equals(-0d)

Answer (score -9):

By using == statement you are comparing values. With equals your are comparing objects.