# Java - Check if input is a positive integer, negative integer, natural number and so on.

Tags: java

Is there any in-built method in Java where you can find the user input's type whether it is positive, or negative and so on? The code below doesn't work. I am trying to find a way to input any in-built method that can do it at the if statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        if(number == int) 
            System.out.println("Number is natural and positive.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of these are possible with insanely short pieces of code, eg variable>0, variable<0

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you really have to avoid operators then use [Math.signum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29)

> Returns the signum function of the argument; zero if the argument is
>   zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument
>   is less than zero.

EDIT : As per the comments, this works for only double and float values. For integer values you can use the method:

[Integer.signum(int i)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum(int))

Comment: Math.signum() works only for double or float values. The question specifically mentions Integer.

Answer (score 31):

What about using the following:

```
int number = input.nextInt();
if (number < 0) {
    // negative
} else {
   // it's a positive
}
```

Comment: The second `if` is redundant... Simply use `else { /*positive*/ }` if you need the context block; or do away with the `else` and it's context block entirely if you don't need it: `if (number < 0) { /*negative*/ } /*positive*/`

Comment: 0 is not positive or negative.  http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58735.html

Comment: @devdanke Yet Java has [signed zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14771363/2908724).

Comment: @bishop  Wow.  Nice find!

Answer (score 7):

(You should you as `Else-If` statement to check the for the three different state (positive, negative, 0)

Here is a simple example (excludes the possibility of non-integer values)

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Compare {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    if( number == 0)
    { System.out.println("Number is equal to zero"); }
    else if (number > 0)
    { System.out.println("Number is positive"); }
    else 
    { System.out.println("Number is negative"); }


  }
 }
```

Comment: incorrect output for two cases; this line `int number = input.nextInt();` cause the wrong output for inputs of -1 and 0

Answer (score 3):

For integers you can use [Integer.signum()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum(int))

> Returns the signum function of the specified int value. (The return value is -1 if the specified value is negative; 0 if the
>   specified value is zero; and 1 if the specified value is positive.)

Answer (score 0):

Use like below code.

```
if(number >=0 ) {
            System.out.println("Number is natural and positive.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `if(number >= 0)`. The fact that you use `int number = input.nextInt();` makes sure that it has to be an Integer.