# How do I check for a negative zero in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I've been trying to figure out how to determine if a double value is `-0.0d`. I googled the problem for a bit and found a few different approaches, however all the threads I found were at least a couple years old and seem to no longer work.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
double x, y;
x = 0;
y = -0;

println(x == y);
println(Double.compare(x, y) == 0);
println(new Double(x).equals(new Double(y)));
println(Double.doubleToLongBits(x) == Double.doubleToLongBits(y));
println(Math.signum(x) == Math.signum(y));
```

All of those print `true`, unfortunately.

The reason I need to distinguish between 0 and -0, if you're wondering, is because I'm trying to parse a double value from user input, and using -0 as a sentinel value in case of an exception.

Comment: "Negative zero" doesn't really make any sense.  Zero is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: This may sound like a cop-out, but why not read the input as a `String`, check for `-0`, and if not then parse it as a double?

Comment: Did you already try `Double.doubleToRawLongBits(0.0) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(-0.0);` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14771363/205233)?

Comment: @David While that is entirely true in a mathematical sense, it isn't in programming. A floating point zero still has a sign bit which is retained.

Comment: @David `-0` does make sense. [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) defines [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) where the sign bit determines whether `+0` or `-0` applies.

Comment: @Filburt thanks, turns out the problem was me missing the `.0` part

Comment: Wouldn’t Double.NaN be an easier sentinel value to check for?

Comment: @StefanZobel Seconded.

Comment: @VGR Absolutely, and now I'm questioning my sanity as to why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `y = -0` instead of `y = -0.0`. `0` is an [integer literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) and there is no `-0` `int` value, it just stays `0` and then is [widened](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to `+0.0d`.You could also use `-(double)0` to do the widening before the negation and get the same result as `-0.0`.

Comment: Just tested this, can confirm it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: Yes -0 is just 0 as integers don't have a negative 0. -0.0 is a double and there is a negative 0.0 +1