# Unexpected result with kotlin contentEquals on DoubleArray

Tags: arrays, floating-point, kotlin, double, comparison

I have a need to compare two DoubleArrays in order to determine if they have the same values in the same order.  To do so I have used the `contentEquals` extension function, however, it treats **0** and **-0** as two different values (comparing them with `==` treats them the same).

For example:

```
val x = doubleArrayOf(1.0,0.0,-0.0)
val y = doubleArrayOf(1.0,0.0, 0.0)

x[0] == y[0] // true
x[1] == y[1] // true
x[2] == y[2] // true

x contentEquals y // false
```

Defining an extension function to do pairwise comparison myself,

```
infix fun DoubleArray.reallyEqual(other:DoubleArray) = (this.size == other.size) && this.zip(other).all {it.first == it.second}

x reallyEqual y // true
```

produces the expected result.

I am not sure if this is a bug, or if this is really the intended result, but it is a surprise as the individual equal tests compare true.

Looking at the source code, we can understand why this is this way.  The contentEquals function delegates to *java.util.Arrays::equals*

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns `true` if the two specified arrays are *structurally* equal to one another,
>  * i.e. contain the same number of the same elements in the same order.
>  */
> @SinceKotlin("1.1")
> @kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
> public inline infix fun DoubleArray.contentEquals(other: DoubleArray): Boolean {
>     return java.util.Arrays.equals(this, other)
> }
> ```

and that method delegates to `Double::equals` which considers these to be different

> Two doubles d1 and d2 are considered equal if:
>
> ```
> new Double(d1).equals(new Double(d2))
> ```
>
> (Unlike the == operator, this method considers NaN equals to itself, and 0.0d unequal to -0.0d.)

Is this the intended behavior, or is the behavior that I am expecting the intended?  I am not sure where bugs/feature requests for Kotlin are supposed to be reported, and this may belong there.  If this is the intended behavior, perhaps a second method which delegates to `==` instead of `Double::equals` should be included in the standard library.  At very least, a note in the documentation that this method relies on `Double::equals` instead of `==` and that the behavior is different.

**Disclaimer:** *I am aware of the risks with precision when comparing double values with equality.  Eventually, I will try to refactor my code so it doesn't rely on equality, but for now, it works with equality tests.  This isn't a question about how to compare two arrays of doubles in general.*

Comment: Here you can report bugs or issue feature requests: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: Well, if you care about precision thing you should consider using BigDecimal and compareTo instead of double.

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771328/java-signed-zero-and-boxing

Comment: How do you override hashCode in this case?  The standard behavior is not inconsistent with the equals contract.