# Difference between 0 and -0 in coding

Tags: python

I hope this isn't too dumb, but is 0 and -0 the same, just as in math? Python returns the first character of a string when either of these are used as index values.

Comment: what would you expect to get for `astr[-0]`. For floats there can be a difference because the FPU you can represent `0.0` and `-0.0`

Comment: `0` and `-0` are the same. `0.0` and `-0.0` are not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is not dumb at all: 0 and -0 are the same in case they are numbers, but when they are strings they are clearly different (one has only one and the other has two characters).

You mention both being index values, which are numbers, so they are equal, as you can see here:

```
Prompt>python
>>> print(0)
0
>>> print(-0)
0
```

In both cases, the output is clearly the same.

In case they would be strings, the length would already show a clear difference:

```
>>> print(len("-0"))
2
>>> print(len("0"))
1
```

For the people, interested in floating point numbers, the equality can be shown as follows:

```
>>> print(0.0+0.0)
0.0
>>> print(-0.0+0.0)
0.0
```

Comment: You say "when they are strings they are clearly different", yet you print them (which calls their string representation functions) and show that they both give the same output string.

Comment: @gspr: I edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: But now you're answering a different question, namely *is there a difference between the strings `"0"` and `"-0"`?* That's clearly not what OP is getting at, because in that question there's nothing special about 0, and OP probably knows that prepending the string `"-"` to any string makes the new string different from the old one.

Comment: This works for me, thanks; might want to add the stuff about it being different with floats, though.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: I've added an example to show the equality for floating point numbers.

Comment: @Dominique: What is your floating point example meant to show?

Comment: @gspr: if you use 0.0 or -0.0, the result stays the same.

Comment: Yes, for that particular calculation. There are many others for which the result does not stay the same. For example `-1.0*0.0` vs `-1.0*(-0.0)`. Or see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I here assume you are talking about `0.0` and `-0.0` as (IEEE-754) *floating point* values. The below does not apply to integers.

One thing having a [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) allows you to do is provide some useful extra information for certain undefined quantities. For example, while [the 2-argument arctangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) is undefined when the horizontal coordinate is 0, the `atan2` function in Python and many other programming languages still distinguish between `atan2(0.0, 0.0)` and `atan2(0.0, -0.0)` (the *second* argument of `atan2` is the horizontal coordinate).

As you say, as actual real numbers, 0 and -0 are the same. And if you think of `atan2` as a function in the mathematical sense, both `atan2(0, 0)` and `atan2(0, -0)` are undefined. Amending the definition to handle these cases – and handle them differently (one returns 0, the other (a floating point approximation of) π) – does conveniently allow the user to avoid a bunch of special-casing in code that uses this function.

Answer (score 1):

Coding is a wide field and it depends on the language and context.

In Python, you have the builtin `int` type for integers and `float` for floating-point numbers.

In the case of integers, there is only a single zero. Both `0` and `-0` are `int` literals that map to that single zero.

However, for floating-point numbers, you have two: positive (`0.`) and negative zero (`-0.`). Take a look at IEEE 754 and questions like [Why do floating-point numbers have signed zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13544342/9305398) for more about this.